# Video in previous slide keeps playing after navigating to next slide

Tags: wordpress, slider

I'm using the [Revolution Slider WordPress plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380) and I'm having trouble getting the video to stop once the user navigates to the next slide. I can't seem to find the option to disable that, if there is any. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Example: If you go [here](http://%E2%9E%A1.ws/isa), click on the first slide, click on the play button that comes up, then navigate to the next slide while the video is playing, you'll notice that the video still plays in the background even though you're on the next slide.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the player when you click on the arrows. Of course, replace the ID of the player with just `iframe` to stop all videos if you have more than one or the ID's will change when you modify slides.

```
$('.tparrows').click(function(){
    //either
    $('.rev_slider').find('#iframe961').get(0).stopVideo();

    //or
    $('.rev_slider').find('iframe').get(0).stopVideo();
});
```

edit:
You need to add `&enablejsapi=1` to the video's url too. But then it will work!